# Close Excel file after following link added to a Shape

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with a project that I want to have something like a "Main Menu" Sheet. I added some shapes to act like buttons linking them with other excel files. What I needed the shapes to do is after clicking them, close this "Main Menu" Sheet as it is only needed to choose what type of sheet I need to use. So the idea is:

I have this "main-menu.xlsm" opened in the first place. Inside it's first sheet named "Main" I have 3 shapes linking to three other excel files "sheet1.xlsx", "sheet2.xlsx"and "sheet3.xlsx". The linking works just fine, but I end up with two Excel's opened, I need to make it so after I click the shape that opens "sheet1.xlsx" it also closes the "main-menu.xlsm".

What I've come across is adding this code to Sheet1(Main):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)

ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
Workbooks("main-menu.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

But unfortunately it is not working with shapes. If instead of a shape I create a Text, link it to one of the files I need and click it, then the code works just fine. Anyone can help me out with this? Thank you for your time and patience reading this and helping if you can.

Comment: So, your shapes exist in the 'Main Menu' sheet of `Workbooks("main-menu.xlsm")`. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Yes it is correct. Except the name of the sheet that was changed to "Main" and it is a sheet of "main-menu.xlsm". The code works for links made with text, but doesn`t for the ones made with shapes.

Comment: Then, try my suggestion from the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next approach, please:

1. Remove the existing link, but copy its reference (firstly, only for one shape...);
2. Create the next `Sub` in a standard module

   `Sub MyShape1_Click()
      Workbooks.Open ("Full name of the previously linked workbook")
      ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
   End Sub`

You need to name each `Sub` in a way to be relevant when you need to assign it to the appropriate shape.

2. Right click on your shape(s), choose "Assign Macro...", select 'Macros in:' ThisWorkbook and look for the above `Sub`. Select it and click `OK'.
3. Enjoy what it will do...

Comment: @Tchambowski: Glad I could help!